# Suddenly getting maxrregcount warnings and undefined reference errors when linking

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, undefined-reference

I maintain the [C+=-flavored CUDA API wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers) library. The library's current commit is relatively-well-tested, with some example programs and  quite a few users. However, sometime very recently (can't say exactly when), and without committing anything new, I now get NVCC warnings during the "dlink" phase of my example programs, e.g.:

```
/path/to/nvcc /path/to/cuda-api-wrappers/examples/modified_cuda_samples/vectorAdd/vectorAdd.cu -dc -o /path/to/cuda-api-wrappers/CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/examples/modified_cuda_samples/vectorAdd/./vectorAdd_generated_vectorAdd.cu.o -ccbin /opt/gcc-5.4.0/bin/gcc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 --std=c++11 -Xcompiler -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -DNVCC -I/path/to/cuda/include -I/path/to/cuda-api-wrappers/src
/path/to/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 --std=c++11 -Xcompiler -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -m64 -ccbin /opt/gcc-5.4.0/bin/gcc -dlink /export/path/to/cuda-api-wrappers/CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/examples/modified_cuda_samples/vectorAdd/./vectorAdd_generated_vectorAdd.cu.o /path/to/cuda/lib64/libcublas_device.a -o /export/path/to/cuda-api-wrappers/CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/./vectorAdd_intermediate_link.o
@O@ptxas info    : 'device-function-maxrregcount' is a BETA feature
@O@ptxas info    : 'device-function-maxrregcount' is a BETA feature
@O@ptxas info    : 'device-function-maxrregcount' is a BETA feature
... this repeats many times ...
```

but the dlink face does conclude. This is already strange, since I haven't explicitly used any beta features.

```
/opt/gcc-5.4.0/bin/g++   -Wall -Wpedantic -O2 -DNDEBUG  -L/path/to/cuda/lib64 -rdynamic CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/examples/modified_cuda_samples/vectorAdd/vectorAdd_generated_vectorAdd.cu.o CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/vectorAdd_intermediate_link.o  -o examples/bin/vectorAdd lib/libcuda-api-wrappers.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lcudart_static -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lnvToolsExt -Wl,-Bstatic -lcudadevrt -Wl,-Bdynamic 
CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/vectorAdd_intermediate_link.o: In function `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_25_cublas_compute_70_cpp1_ii_f0559976':
link.stub:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `__fatbinwrap_25_cublas_compute_70_cpp1_ii_f0559976'
CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/vectorAdd_intermediate_link.o: In function `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_25_xerbla_compute_70_cpp1_ii_cd7f3ad3':
link.stub:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `__fatbinwrap_25_xerbla_compute_70_cpp1_ii_cd7f3ad3'
CMakeFiles/vectorAdd.dir/vectorAdd_intermediate_link.o: In function `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_23_nrm2_compute_70_cpp1_ii_8edbce95':
link.stub:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `__fatbinwrap_23_nrm2_compute_70_cpp1_ii_8edbce95'
... more udnefined reference errors here ...
```

My question: Why would this happen and how do I circumvent/avoid/resolve it?

Notes:

- I'm using separable compilation
- I'm getting these specific errors with CUDA 9.1 and a SM 5.2 device (no 7.0).
- The `CMakeLists.txt` is [here](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).
- I'm obviously clearing `CMakeCache.txt` before building.
- This has happened to me both on a GNU/Linux Mint 18.3 and Fedora 26. On the first machine there have been some apt-get dist-upgrade's done, and now GCC is up to version 5.5.0, in case that matters. On the second machine - there really has been no change that I'm aware of; same compiler and CUDA version.

Comment: What CUDA version is this? If I were to guess (and I can't do anything else because you have no repro case), I would guess that something in CMake is broken. Note it is compute 70 which is missing, that would point to some sort of mixing of CUDA versions or trying to compile and link for an architecture that doesn't exist in the CUDA version you are using. Broken build caches are also a problem in CMake when versions of things change

Comment: @talonmies: 9.1, and I'm clearing the CMakeCache. I'll try using a different CMake version maybe.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer / workaround:

This issue only seems to occur when [libcublas](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas) is involved. If I remove `/path/to/cuda/lib64/libcublas_device.a` from the `-dlink` phase command-line, all warnings and errors go away (including from later stages). And in fact, my wrapper library is oblivious of cublas, not sure why CMake is adding it; it's not in `$CUDA_LIBRARIES`. See also:

[Why does CMake force the use of libcublas with separable compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583205/why-does-cmake-force-the-use-of-libcublas)